# animation on layout with change activity

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, android-transitions

[image]

What I want, when I click on the login button of the first activity the yellow part slides down and the next activity opens. when I click on the signup button of the second screen(login screen) the yellow part of the second screen slides up and the first activity (sign up Activity)opens. I have used slide-down animation on the linear layout on the first screen it works but not working smoothly. Any help??

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        mSignUpButton = findViewById(R.id.btnSigUp);
        linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        mGotoLoginActivityButton=findViewById(R.id.btnLoginSignUpActivity);
        slideDown= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide_down);

      
//listener for Login button
        mGotoLoginActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //setValidation();

                Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                linearLayout.startAnimation(slideDown);

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't use two separated Activities for this purpose, use one and login and create account views should be packed into `Fragment`s. this way will be way easier to animate between two views/fragments in on `Activity`, but if you really must use `Activity` then use [Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity) (probably with shared elements), not animations, as these are working in one `Activity` during its runtime when visible (and you are currently running new `Activity`, which cover old one)

Comment: it's not necessary to use activities. necessary is to use that type of animation